# Video.js for Vimeo

Tags: html5-video, vimeo, video.js

I use video.js for vimeo. Played on the desktop in a custom player with my styles, it's good, but on the tablets and mobiles played in a default browse player. Why? I want custom player in mobile too. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In a recent version video.js was updated to use the custom skin on touch devices, so you might try updating your version. But this will still only make a difference on tablets that don't go to fullscreen video. On iOS devices and most(?) android devices, whenever the video goes to fullscreen it uses the native controls, and there's nothing we can do in the browser to change that. Hopefully in the future the devices will adopt the `requestFullscreen` browser API so we can use custom controls in that context.